# Extra } or forgotten \endgroup in table* and figure* environment

Tags: tables, floats

I have following latex problem. Whenever I use the figure* or table* environment I get the error message:

*Extra } or forgotten \endgroup*

However I can't find any "}" that aren't necessary. I don't get the error when I use figure or table environment instead. I use figure*/table* because I need tables/figures over two columns.

The code compiles but the word "table" or "figure" appears in my compiled pdf.

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[caption=false]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[b]
    \centering
    \rule{5cm}{5cm}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

I couldn't find a solution anywhere. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please extend this to a full minimal self contained example that others can copy and test as is (you can replace the image by `\rule{5cm}{5cm}` as we do not have your image.

Comment: Unrelated: don't use the `center` env to center inside floats. Sounds strange, but `center` adds extra vertical space above and below, as does the float, so here `center` gives excessive spacing. Replace `\begin{center}` with `\centering` and delete `\end{center}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Remove contents supposedly unrelated  with the problem,  checking  after each deletion that  the error is still there, and it is not a different error. Then do the same with  packages, settings, and  macro definitions of the preamble that are no longer used (e.g. remove `tabularx`  package if there are not tables) or are  unrelated with the problem  (e.g., `geometry` package if change of margins will not change the error). Finally, change your image by `example-image`. This is the  MWE (Minimal Working -- reproducible -- Example) to show, but now you see the problem, right?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Based on them I found out, that this only happens with a certain combination of packages that the template I'm using imports. I updated my example accordingly. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: Package `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` caused the issue, just remove it and try...

Comment: I'm not sure if it is related to the problem, but the package [`subfigure`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is considered obsolete, and is in fact superseded by [`subfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfig). So I guess that in any case, you should not use both and you should use only `subfig`.

Comment: There are more issues than `fixltx2e` and `subfigure`:  Error: The package option caption=false is obsolete. Please pass this option to the subfig package instead and do *not* load the caption package anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working now

Answer (score 1):

- `subfigure` (which is obsolete) and `subfige` are not compatible. Remove both of them.
- `IEEEtran` has own definition for captions. It is not recommended to use package `caption`
- images over two columns, inserted by `figure*` are appear on the top of the next page from point its inserting in document. If you add position option `[b]` it will ne moved on the end of document, so don't use positioning options.
- in a case, that you like that it appear at bottom of the same or next page, you need to use the package `stfloats` (see MWE below).

```
\documentclass[conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
%\usepackage[caption=false]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subfig}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{stfloats}   %   <---
\usepackage{lipsum}     %   <---

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[b]
    \centering
    \rule{\linewidth}{5cm}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]